# Installed all fonts from another laptop - now Power symbol & other symbols are missing

Tags: fonts, windows-8-fonts

I made the mistake of moving my Font folder from my Windows 7 laptop to my Windows 8.1 laptop and hitting "Install all."

Now some of the Symbols aren't appearing - for example the "Power" Symbol on the Start Screen.

Here are a few screen shots:

Mailbox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXVNw.png

Start Screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFID2.png

I'm assuming it is not as easy as finding the problem font and re-installing it - but if it was I wouldn't know which one to fix.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract and install the execuatable given below and check. If it asks to remove then remove it and reinstall the instance and check

[appearance-problem-won-8-segoe_ui_symbol](http://www.eightforums.com/attachments/performance-maintenance/16081d1360065650-appearance-problem-won-8-segoe_ui_symbol.zip)

Comment: Worked perfectly after installing the font and rebooting, thank you!